# Trying to find book I read from library about a lone person crash landing on an alien planet

Tags: story-identification, aliens, choose-your-own-adventure

This was a book I loved reading and it was done in the style that you made choices of how to do things and then turn page to see what would happen.

It had some beautiful illustrations, but for the life of me I can't remember the name. Also you could die and much of the flora and fauna were dangerous.

If anyone could think of what it was, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Was the premise that you started out crashed on the planet, or was that one of the possible story routes?

Comment: You started out crashed on an alien planet, and it had many different biomes too.

Comment: Don't know the books well enough, but that sounds like a Choose Your Own Adventure book. The list of those books can be found here. http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Choose_Your_Own_Adventure_books

Comment: Nah none of them seem familar, it had vibrant illustrations and it was in the 90s I borrowed the book. Does that help?

Comment: http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1044115.The_Planet_Of_Terror

Comment: Nope not that one, just got it in order...

Comment: I am sorry, still searching though....

Comment: Were they color illustrations then? I have a CYOA book in mind, which included a phaser with kill and stun settings (which, as a child, I noted never had a situation where you weren't better off using the "kill" setting) and a helmet which amplified your intelligence, but I think that was the standard CYOA line illustrations.

Comment: Can you guess when you read this, when the book was probably pubilshed, and what language you read it in?  If so, please edit your question to include these  information.

Comment: What was on the front cover?

Comment: There is a comprehensive-looking list of "gamebooks" on [this page](http://www.gamebooks.org/index.php), and you can also restrict the list by country--for example if you're from the US, look at [this list](http://www.gamebooks.org/show_country.php?id=1), and there's also a list of [books in the sci-fi genre](http://www.gamebooks.org/show_category.php?id=33). mbocek's answer looks plausible, but if that's not it, could it be [Monsters of Doorna](http://www.gamebooks.org/show_item.php?id=14)? If you do a google image search for that title you'll find some examples of the art.

Comment: ...and if the one you're thinking of had color illustrations (please say so if it did, along with the country you read it in), another possibility is something in the [Twisted Journeys](http://www.gamebooks.org/show_series.php?id=1226) series since the description says they had "full-color comic book panels", or [The Planet of Terror](http://www.gamebooks.org/show_item.php?id=3154) from the [Which Way?](http://www.gamebooks.org/show_series.php?id=490) series which were "printed in a large, full-color format".

Comment: I am sorry for delay, the illustrations were coloured, it was in the UK in a Scottish library and I think you had equipment you could use. I am sorry real sorry not much help here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be "**Can you survive on an Alien Planet?**" By David Fickling. It has never been published on its own but appeared in the collection [Planetfall (ed. Douglas Arthur Hill)](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/440786.Planetfall). It is a choose-your-own adventure story featuring full-color illustrations on most of the pages, and tells the story of an astronaut crash-landing on a planet called Abthaze, claimed to be the most dangerous planet in the galaxy.

In the beginning of the story, you are instructed to choose just three pieces of gear to bring with you from your crashed ship, which may or may not help you along the way. You encounter a number of dangerous plants and animals along with other hazards and move through different zones of the planet, like swamp, forest, and plains, before reaching an alien beacon that you can use to signal for rescue. You are also able to die if you make enough wrong choices.

Unfortunately, I was not able to find any pictures from the story that might jog your memory.

Comment: THAT'S IT, THAT'S IT!!! THANK YOU, I RECOGNIZE THE COVER!

Comment: Would you believe that I had the exact same experience as you with this same book? That's why I remembered it :)

Comment: Thank you so much, and yeah it's not easy to find, but cover is immediately recognizable.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be **Enemy Mine** by Barry B. Longyear?

Comment: I don't believe that was a "Choose Your Own Adventure" kind of book.

Comment: It isn't I just didn't read the description correctly, I'm sorry.