# Kids illustrated book about being stranded on an alien planet with multiple choice questions

Tags: story-identification, choose-your-own-adventure

I've looked before and just spent over an our trawling through Google images, but like the title says: Does anyone remember a book like this?

It wasn't a novel, but a series of nice illustrations of various scenes on an alien planet that you've crash landed on. Each page had a question with multiple choice answers but if I remember correctly only one answer was correct and would allow you to survive. There was very little other text. I think the goal was to reach some sort of crystal obelisk that you could use to get help.

It's probably awful, but I just remember it filling me with wonder as a kid; does anyone know what this is?

Comment: There were a lot of "make your own adventure" books like that a few years ago. You'd need to narrow this down **a lot** to get an answer.

Comment: Possible Duplicate - http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/87405/trying-to-find-book-i-read-from-library-about-a-lone-person-crash-landing-on-an/92285#92285

Comment: If not...try this list - https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Choose_Your_Own_Adventure_books

Comment: Did you have to solve simple puzzles and math problems to find out the correct page to go to, by any chance?

Answer (score 3):

This may be *[The Star Crystal](https://archive.org/details/Be_an_Interplanetary_Spy_06_The_Star_Crystal)* from the *Be an Interplanetary Spy* series of game books.  The book is available in its entirety at the Internet Archive.

Here is a sample of two facing pages:

[image: Pages 102-103]

If it is not that one, there are others from the series [also available online](https://archive.org/search.php?query=%22interplanetary%20spy%22).

Answer (score 1):

Planetfall (1986), ISBN 0-19-278113-8
By Douglass Hill
Sounds like the 'Can you survive on an alien planet?' part.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You can make this a better answer by including some details showing how it matches the question.